# Php returning encoded data to ajax when it's not even in json_encode

Tags: php, jquery

The file I post below is being ajaxed from jQuery.
It returns encoded data (with question mark symbols and all). I am not even echoing the data or anything.
 The only thing I send to the client is json_encode. The json_encode data comes after the encoded data.
When I do not call my base64_extension function, it all works properly.

EDIT
The code is no longer spitting out the encoded data. However, the function is returning 4 (not image). I am trying to understand why.

```
function base64_extension($base64)
{
$base64 = str_replace("data:image/png;base64,", "", $base64);

$base64 = imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode($base64));

if (!$base64) {
    return 0; /* Not image */
}

if (imagepng($base64, "tmp.png")) {
    imagedestroy($base64);
    unlink('tmp.png');
    return 1;
} else if (imagejpeg($base64, "tmp.jpg")) {
    imagedestroy($base64);
    unlink('tmp.jpg');
    return 2;
} else if (imagegif($base64, "tmp.gif")) {
    imagedestroy($base64);
    unlink('tmp.gif');
    return 3;
} else {
    return 4; /* Not image */
}
}
```

That is the function, here is the rest :

```
echo json_encode(array("status" => "success", "dreamID" => $data['dreamId'], "mime" => base64_extension($_POST['dream_pic'])));
```

mime returns as 1. So the function seems to work. Not sure why a bunch of encoded data gets returned to ajax. Thanks!

Comment: What do `imagecreatefromstring` and `imagedestroy` do?

Comment: Could you include the additional "encoded data", which gets returned? You can inspect them in the "developer tools" toolbar of your browser. Are those PHP warnings or notices?

Comment: @CrouchingKitten There are no warnings or errors. I fixed this problem by passing in a second param (save location) to imagepng, imagegif, and imagejpeg. The problem now is that those functions are returning false for some reason :\

Comment: Could you show us your `ajax` call code?